# My keyring info references "The Secret Service was already initialized" - Am I being hacked?

Tags: keyrings

Am I being hacked???

```
Feb 20 07:49:16 USER gnome-keyring-daemon[1741]: message repeated 2 times: [ couldn't set environment variable in session: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files]
Feb 20 07:49:17 USER  gnome-keyring-daemon[1741]: The Secret Service was already initialized
Feb 20 07:49:17 USER  gnome-keyring-daemon[1741]: The SSH agent was already initialized
Feb 20 07:49:17 USER  gnome-keyring-daemon[1741]: The GPG agent was already initialized
Feb 20 07:49:17 USER  gnome-keyring-daemon[1741]: The PKCS#11 component was already initialized
Feb 20 07:49:17 USER polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c1 (system bus name :1.46 [/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Feb 20 07:49:18 USER  dbus[570]: [system] Rejected send message, 7 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.50" (uid=0 pid=2433 comm="/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.5" (uid=0 pid=838 comm="NetworkManager ")
Feb 20 07:49:49 USER  gnome-keyring-daemon[1741]: keyring alias directory: /home/USER /.local/share/keyrings
Feb 20 07:57:08 USER unix_chkpwd[3339]: password check failed for user (roseleo)
Feb 20 07:57:08 USER  compiz: pam_unix(unity:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=1000 tty= ruser= rhost=  user=xxxx
Feb 20 08:11:15 USER  dbus[570]: [system] Rejected send message, 7 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.50" (uid=0 pid=2433 comm="/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.5" (uid=0 pid=838 comm="NetworkManager ")
Feb 20 08:11:23 USER  dbus[570]: [system] Rejected send message, 7 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.50" (uid=0 pid=2433 comm="/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.5" (uid=0 pid=838 comm="NetworkManager ")
Feb 20 08:17:01 USER CRON[4440]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 20 08:17:01 USER  CRON[4440]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Comment: Why do you think you are being hacked?

Comment: Because it reads: The Secret Service was already initialized
The SSH agent was already initialized
The GPG agent was already initialized Ok? or am I just being silly?

Comment: Believe it or not, but these are bona fide warnings. If you are interested, you can find them in the source code [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/utopic/gnome-keyring/utopic/view/head:/daemon/gkd-main.c).

Comment: // , The, ah, name seems a bit over-alarming.

Answer (score 6):

No.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: To the downvoter: please explain why this needs anything more than 2 letters to answer the question? (mind that OP did nothing but dump a bunch of lines and did not even consider to have a search for any of these lines).

Comment: @Rinzwind I didn't downvote, but bad answers are bad answers, irrespective of the question. And you can't call this one a perfectly stunning answer ;)

Comment: @seth It 100% perfectly answers the question ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind There is a difference between a "good" answer and a "correct" answer :-) (former math teacher here).

Comment: // , Good answers add context, just like good questions.

Answer (score 6):

Believe it or not, but these are bona fide warnings issued by the `gnome-keyring-daemon` process. If you are interested, you can find them in the source code [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/utopic/gnome-keyring/utopic/view/head:/daemon/gkd-main.c).

Simply googling error messages is often a good way to figure out if the error is critical, or a mere warning.

Comment: // , Why does the gnome-keyring-daemon process refer to this as the "Secret Service?" The `secrets_started` variable, which determines whether to display this error, seems to have a one-to-one correspondence, or at least enough of a correspondence to merit an explanation of why this particular dbus starting means that it's secret. 

The only section of the code which sets secrets_started to true follows:  

 (dbus_started) {
    secrets_started = TRUE;
    if (!gkd_dbus_secrets_startup ()) {
     secrets_started = FALSE;
     return FALSE;
    }